# How do I count everytime I press a key down?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to count everytime I hit the left button my code looks like this

```
    import pyautogui
    import pygame
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
           if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                print (sequentially the amount of times i've hit left)
```

Comment: Increment a variable

Comment: Increment a variable and print that.

Comment: so like x = 1 and than print x +=1? is that correct?

Comment: Try that, see if it works

Comment: Im a noob I apoligize. XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store the data in a variable and increment it:

```
import pyautogui
import pygame
Number_of_Presses = 0
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
       if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            Number_of_Presses += 1
            print (Number_of_Presses)
```

Should work great.

Answer (score 2):

make a variable to store the number of times the key has been pressed:

```
import pygame
left=0

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
            left+=1
print(left)
```

**note**: you may want to put the event loop inside of a while loop so it will run more than once.